# How to extract html <p> content in a html attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extract, blogger

I want to extract `<p>` content in a html attributes, `<meta content='**I want to extract here**' name='description'/>` . How can be done the job.
I am using blogger.com, So in blogger.com I want to extract the `<p>` content in meta tag. Please help me. I tried a lot but failed.

Comment: You mean that you want to extract the content from a `<meta>` tag and put it into a `<p>` tag?

Comment: var html = '';
$("head meta").each(function () {
    html += $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
});
alert(html);

Comment: No! I want to extract the content from a `<p>` tag and put it into a `<meta>` tag.

Comment: When you want to do it ? During the page load ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add the Id `metaTag` to the tag meta

```
var metaTag = document.getElementById("metaTag").content;

document.write(metaTag);
```

Comment: Where I will add it? In head section, with `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Run this JavaScript on document load.

```js
// JavaScript
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
console.log(p.textContent);
var metaTag = document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]');
console.log(metaTag);
metaTag.setAttribute("content",p.textContent);
console.log(metaTag);
```

```html
<!-- Sample HTML -->
<meta content='**I want to extract here**' name='description'/>
<p>some text</p>
```

Comment: It does not work. Unable to retrive data from `<p>` tag in content attributes.

Comment: JavaScript should run on document load.
Add the JavaScript code inside `<script>` tag or separate file at end of HTML file.
Run my code, it's working.

Comment: Yes, here working. But when I put it into blogger.com in head or body tag it looking something this, `<script type='text/javascript'>
var p = document.getElementsByTagName(&quot;p&quot;)[0];
console.log(p.textContent);
var metaTag = document.querySelector("meta[name=&quot;description&quot;]");
console.log(metaTag);
metaTag.setAttribute(&quot;content&quot;,p.textContent);
console.log(metaTag);
</script>` I mean, `"` converts to `&quot;`. If I write a post and put some text into `<p>` it is not extracting into meta content atributes. and exacly I want that.

Comment: May be the website doesn't allow `scripts` inside its content for reason of [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Comment: Also i don't understand what's the use of modifying the meta tag on document load. Meta tag are used by web crawlers, search engines. So changing it on document load is really of no use.

Comment: I tried it now with Notepad++ its does not working. But how works here in this websites.?  I want to do it in order to create meta description for web crawlers

Comment: I just joined  jsfiddle.net . But I dont know how to share. Please help me , I badly need it.

Comment: Oh! got it. the link is, https://jsfiddle.net/mehrabtamim/upf21h3f/1/ .

Comment: You added same code as mine in the answer and it is working if you open the console and check.

Comment: Yes! I added the same code. But I am unable to get the output. How to open console?

Comment: `ctrl + shift + c`

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. I got it.

Comment: Glad you got it! In that case you can accept the answer :)

Comment: Bro, One more question. In console the code works. But can't i show it in head section of the page source? I mean the meta tag does not show in page source within head section. Any way to solve it?

Comment: It's dynamically modified. You won't see the change in source file. See the source code in developer console, it'll show the change.